# <div> acting as a background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a "help center" in HTML and i need to change the background when i hover on a selection, a `div`, I "figured" it out a little, but I have a problem, when I hover on the `div` I made the background change, but it hides everything else when i hover on the `div`, like for example, the div that changes the background is on the top of all others, so it hides all of them... There the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vj9ga9r/1/)
So I want to change the `body` background if possible, or make like i made and put a `div` as a background, to change it. I tried to make it like this:

```
selection:hover>body{
    background-image:url(DIR);
}
```

But... doesn't work... So yeah, thanks to give it a try!

Comment: `>` is a [child combinator](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#child-combinators). But probably, the `body` isn't a child of your element. And currently, there is no way to select ancestors.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Try clarifying and making your question an actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to implement with jQuery, which is a popular javascript library

I would do something like

```
$( "#someID" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "#anotherElement" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
  }, function() {
    $( "#anotherElement" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
  }
);
```

which will target the element with ID "someID" and then set the background-color of "anotherElement" to red while you hover over "someID", and set it back to white once you leave. You could also just target the "body" element, by doing:

```
$( "#someID" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
  }, function() {
    $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
  }
);
```

To include jquery in your HTML document you can load the jquery library from google's cdn by adding

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your html document.

To call the code above, wrap it in a self-calling function like so:

```
  <script>
    (function(){
      CODE GOES HERE
    })();
  </script>
```

If this does not immediately make sense to you, you should read this: [Short Introduction to jQuery](http://html.net/tutorials/javascript/lesson19.php)

<del>I haven't tested the code, so there might be typos or mistakes, but the concept is usable</del> ;)

EDIT: I have now tested my code.. It does work, please see below

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:white">
<div id="someID">
<p>If you hover over this the color changes</p>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        $( "#someID" ).hover(
            function() {
                $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
            }, function() {
                $( "body" ).css( "background-color", "white" );
            }
        );
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well your code doesn't work, but i'll put myself into jQuery :D.
And Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible so when you hover on the div, it changes the image ?

i've tried that: `$( "body" ).css( "background-image", "url(../img/space.jpg)" );`, oh and i didn't learn jQuery...

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I think you need to have a background image set on the element (in css or inline) before it will work.